# Help locating a short science fiction story - history started in the 1700's

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago I read a very short science fiction story set in contemporary times about society accidentally discovering that reality/the universe only began in the mid 1700's and all of our collective history from before that period seemed to be fabricated but there is no additional insight into what this all means. The story plot focuses around how this knowledge changes the main character's perception of life and his relationships with his family.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You say you read this "years ago;" approximately when would that have been?  (To the nearest decade anyway.)  Do you recall if you read this in a magazine, an anthology or online?

Comment: Can you recall any more details about the story, such as who discovered that the world began around 1750, how this was discovered, and what kind of effect it had on the main character and his family?

Comment: possibly inspired by this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_chronology_(Fomenko)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds a little like "Noman's Land" by Lucius Shepard, in which human history since 1850 or so - and the protagonists' entire memories - turn out to be no more than a dream or simulation within the collective minds of the white spiders which have supplanted the human race.

Originally published in Isaac Asimov's Science Fiction Magazine, Oct 1988; reprinted in the collection "The Ends Of The Earth" (1992).

Excerpt:

> "They weren't dreams, they were experiences of other lives. Men,
> women, children. All from different eras, some of them Indian lives
> from pre-colonial times. None earlier than that. It wasn't that I was
> watching them. I was inside their heads, living their days and nights.
> And it was from these dreams that I began to understand the truth,
> that the spiders had been transported off-island ... a long, long time
> ago. They'd been carried to the mainland, back to Europe on the
> colonial vessels and then gradually had spread to Asia, Africa.
> Everywhere. By my estimate their population had come to span the world
> by the mid-nineteenth century. I very much doubt that humanity
> survived into the twentieth. Of course what I know of human history
> belies that. . . that's part of their fabrication. But in reality the
> last hundred years or so of mankind must have been awful. People dying
> and dying. The population shrinking to a mere handful of souls who
> hadn't been bitten."
>
> It took him a long moment to absorb what she had said. "Now wait a
> minute! We're living proof of..."
>
> "No, we're not," she said. "We're not alive. We never were." He tried
> to interrupt, but she talked over him. "I don't fully understand it.
> Or perhaps I do. I can't be sure. It's difficult to explain things in
> human terms, because though the spiders with their poison have managed
> to ensure a kind of human survival, I have no idea of their
> motivations ... or if they even have motivations. This may all be just
> reflex on their part. Or maybe it's that they've become a unity,
> intelligent in a way, because of a symbiotic use of our genetic
> material. A group mind or something of the sort. Maybe the best
> analogy would be to say . . . Have you heard about the concept of
> people's personalities being translated into computer software? That's
> similar to what the spiders have done. Transformed our genetic
> material into a biological analogue of software."